# Keras-text ValueError when splitting dataset using train_val_split() or update_test_indices()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, text-classification, data-processing

**THE GOAL:**
I am trying to use keras-text to classify text strings into 5 different classes. I'm working with article titles which I use to assign a conference to this article. Problems occur in preprocessing:

I am using the dataset() function from keras_text.data which takes as input X(input data), y(labels belonging to data) and a tokenizer. I use the standard wordtokenizer. For X I use a numpy array of shape (21643, 1), for y I use a numpy array of shape (21634,).

when trying to use .update_test_indices(test_size=0.1) I get te following error:

`ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [21643, 108215]`

Every input string can have 1 out of 5 labels. As you can see there is an inconsistency in input length and sample length. The length of the samples is exactly 5 times as long as the input. If I change the samples so that only 1 out of 4 labels is assigned, the shape changes to (86572,) which are exactly 4 times as long as the input. **So it seems like the labels are multiplied by the inputs**.

when I print the number of classes by using keras_text.data.dataset.num_classes it seems that only 1 class is recognized, I do not know why this is.

*What kind of input format does dataset() need and how can I use update_test_indices()?*

My full code:

```
from keras_text.processing import WordTokenizer
from keras_text.data import Dataset
import numpy as np

def readFile(file):
    X = []
    y = []
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            nr, label, input = line.rstrip().split('\t')
            X.append(input)
            #y.append(label)
            if label == 'ISCAS':
                y.append(1)
                continue
            if label == 'SIGGRAPH':
                y.append(2)
                continue
            if label == 'WWW':
                y.append(3)
                continue
            if label == 'INFOCOM':
                y.append(4)
                continue
            if label == 'VLDB':
                y.append(5)
            else:
                print('wrong',label)
    npX = np.asarray(X)
    npX = npX.reshape(len(X), 1)
    npy = np.asarray(y)
    npy = npy.reshape(len(X))
    return npX, npy

X, y = readFile('Trainset.txt')
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

tokenizer = WordTokenizer()
ds = Dataset(X, y, tokenizer=tokenizer)
ds.update_test_indices(test_size=0.1)
print(ds.num_classes)
ds.save('dataset')
```

**as output I get:**

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
(21643, 1)
(21643,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 42, in <module>
    ds.update_test_indices(test_size=0.1)
  File "..\site-packages\keras_text\data.py", line 54, in update_test_indices
    self._train_indices, self._test_indices = next(sss.split(self.X, self.y))
  File "..\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 1203, in split
    X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
  File "..\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 229, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "..\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 204, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [21643, 86572]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**UPDATE:**
I found that the problem only occurs in a multi-class situation. If I would change the labels to only two classes, it works. However, I do not know how to use multiple classes. *Can someone help me?*

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the labels are encoded as one-hot vectors in the constructor of `Dataset()`, but this isn't taken into account for the split.
Commenting `.flatten()` on line 42 of data.py seems to fix this; I haven't trained a full model with it yet, though.